# Is Action object deprecated? What is its replacement

Tags: playframework-2.6

Looking at the documentation at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Action$, it seems `Action` object is deprecated. What is its replacement?

Answer (score 0):

It seems `ActionBuilder` is the replacement

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.AbstractController